# Arcpy Data Driven Script no index layer

Tags: arcpy, data-driven-pages

**Problem**: Data Driven Pages index layer, which is updated within a python script by replacing the source data, is disappearing when the DDP are later called in the script to export pdfs. Specifically, it is the Spatial Join which replaces the GDB feature class followed in a single run of the script by the DDP processes that is not working.

**Attempted Solutions**: Refresh call for DDP; no effect. Refresh TOC and Active View; no effect. Input a time delay (of up to 40 minutes); no effect. Attempted find & replace workspace, but kept throwing an error.

**Current work around**: Run the script to completion commenting out the DDP portion, then comment out all other functions and run the DDP portion.

**Desired end**: Script can run completely (all parts) without being babysat.

This is the tail end of the code (admin got cranky over the code being too long; if you need more, let me know):

```
arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis(target_features=selected_URD, join_features=selected_ugcable, out_feature_class=URD_CABLE, join_operation="JOIN_ONE_TO_ONE", join_type="KEEP_ALL", field_mapping=fmap, match_option="INTERSECT")
print "URD join with UG cable with non-injected lengths summed."
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
arcpy.RefreshTOC()
#testURD.replaceDataSource('r"' + str(os.path.join(str(os.getcwd()),tempGDB)) + '"', "FILEGDB_WORKSPACE", "URD_CABLE")
print "Map refreshed."

#Update of Data Driven Pages with new data and export to PDF. If the output PDF is nothing but blank pages, increase the number of seconds in the time.sleep function.
mxd.dataDrivenPages.refresh()
ddp = mxd.dataDrivenPages
indexLayer = ddp.indexLayer
ddp.exportToPDF('Injected_&_Non-Injected_Cable_' + str(datetime.date.today()) + '.pdf', page_range_type = 'ALL', multiple_files = 'PDF_SINGLE_FILE', image_quality = 'BEST')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like the lock on the mxd was causing the problem. If anyone else runs into the same issue, just reassign the mxd above the DDP refresh command and everything is happy.

```
arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis(target_features=selected_URD, join_features=selected_ugcable, out_feature_class=URD_CABLE, join_operation="JOIN_ONE_TO_ONE", join_type="KEEP_ALL", field_mapping=fmap, match_option="INTERSECT")
print "URD join with UG cable with non-injected lengths summed."

#Update of Data Driven Pages with new data and export to PDF. If the output PDF is nothing but blank pages, increase the number of seconds in the time.sleep function.
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument('CableInjection.mxd')
mxd.dataDrivenPages.refresh()
ddp = mxd.dataDrivenPages
ddp.exportToPDF('Injected_&_Non-Injected_Cable_' + str(datetime.date.today()) + '.pdf', page_range_type = 'ALL', multiple_files = 'PDF_SINGLE_FILE', image_quality = 'BEST')
```